# multiple routes and function in bottle framework

Tags: python, forms, post, bottle

I'm trying to modify already existing code, simply add form to add photos.

**python:**

```
@route('/photos/add')
@jinja_view('add.html')
@post('/photos/add')
def upload_func():
    upload = request.files.get('pic')
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
    if ext not in ('.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg'):
        return "ext is not allowed"
    save_path = "/src/photo_gallery/photos"
    upload.save(save_path)
    return "photo is saved"
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/photos/add" method="post">
    <div align="center">
        <label>Picture</label>
        <input type="file" name="pic" required>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Info</label>
        <input type="text" name="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="add">
    </div>
</form>
```

**server log:**
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/empty/python/bottle/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)

File "/home/empty/python/bottle/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1740, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)

File "/home/empty/python/bottle/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bottle.py", line 3635, in wrapper
    result = func(*args, **kwargs)

File "/home/empty/python/bottle/src/photo_gallery/app.py", line 50, in upload_func
    name, ext = os.path.splitext(upload.filename)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filename'
127.0.0.1 - - [22/Dec/2016 23:20:42] "GET /photos/add HTTP/1.1" 500 751

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have linked the url path `/photos/add` to the callback function `upload_func`. It looks like you want to support two request types (GET and POST), then function decorators should look like this:

```
@route('/photos/add', method=['GET', 'POST'])
@jinja_view('add.html')
def upload_func():
    # ...
```

Take a look at:

https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-routing
https://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/api.html#bottle.Bottle.route

Please also note that the code should not be written like this - too complex